# Why does this installation fail?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installer

On Windows 10 Professional, I try to uninstall an installed program from its installer, by running

```
    > msiexec /x "\path\to\installer.msi" /quiet
```

Then a window is popped out to say

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.

What does it mean and how can I solve the problem?

The log file produced by adding

```
> msiexec /x "\path\to\installer.msi" /L*V "C:\package.log"
```

to the command is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24231198/)

Comment: It means the installation failed.  An installation log was created, we would need that, to determine the actual cause of the failure.

Comment: where is the installation log?

Comment: Use something like `/L*V "C:\package.log"` that will always generate a log.  [I easily found out how to do that though](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=installation+log+msiexec&*)

Comment: You should supply us the relevant information in the body of the question, the relevant information in general, isn't more then 10 lines.  Everythinbg before the error isn't really that important.  *I don't do Google Drive...*

Comment: The word "error" is scatterd at the beginning, middle, and end of the log file. The log file has 1146 lines, too many to be put into the post.

Comment: Can you put the log somewhere useful like pastebin.com? Google docs is borderline unusable for this.

Comment: That said I did see at least one "error" line that mentioned an exact error, it was the 4th or 5th error. I can't find it any more because, you know, GDocs is just *awful* and copy/paste to notepad just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The error line that appears to be failing is

> MSI (s) (34:3C) [16:38:44:049]: Product: ABC\XYZService -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action _5C826085_D7CC_494E_84D1_92688716E901, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\EFG\ABC\XYZService\ServiceInstaller.exe, command: -u "-service=c:/Program Files/EFG/PartitionUpdaterService/XYZService.exe" -framework4

So you need to either fix your serviceinstaller.exe, or the command you are passing to it.

The failing program (or failing to return a successful error code at least) is

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EFG\ABC\XYZService\ServiceInstaller.exe

The command it is failing to run:

> -u "-service=c:/Program Files/EFG/PartitionUpdaterService/XYZService.exe" -framework4

The full command being

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EFG\ABC\XYZService\ServiceInstaller.exe -u "-service=c:/Program Files/EFG/PartitionUpdaterService/XYZService.exe" -framework4
```

It also looks like it tried to print out that entire message to the screen for you to a dialog box. Did you show us the full error or just the "problem" line? I ask because just below that error is the details of what looks like a dialogue box with almost word for word the above error message.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted the log file elsewhere. I showed you the content of the log file created by the second command in my post. The quoted message in your reply is basically the one quoted in my question.

Comment: Basically yes, essentially no. You missed out the entire part where it stated what command failed doing what. I'll edit to be clearer.

Comment: @Tim if this is a program or installer you have create then you need to make sure that the program being executed can run that command correctly, otherwise you need to contact whoever made it and report this to them.